# Can not evaluate variable in debugger

Tags: android, debugging

Sometimes I have problems while I am in debug mode. I put breakpoint on some variable and try to evaulate it. But my evaluator says : "cannot find local variable".

I don't understand what is going on. I uploaded image so you can see how this situation looks like.

[image]

Comment: sometimes it's ok for Android Studio. The debugger is just not perfect

Comment: It is not ok. I spend hours not being able to debug my code!